# Apache POI comparing 2 columns data in excel

Tags: excel, apache, compare, apache-poi

I have been asked to compare 2 specific columns in an excel sheet using apache POI. I have compared the whole sheet and got results back, but any ideas how to compare 2 specific columns only?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Loop over all the rows, then fetch those two columns by index?

Comment: Thank u im not sure on indexes but ill give it a shot! 

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator